# When multiple observations are present for a variable in a matrix of observations, picking the most variable observation per variable in R

Tags: r, filtering

I have a dataframe of the following format, and as you can see there are multiple variables associated with each gene (for instance, the first two rows are both associated with gene X1).

How do I pick the most variable probe for X1, the most variable probe for X2 and the most variable probe for X3? I will calculate the variability using median absolute deviation for each row to give me a measure of variability. The dataframe's dimensions are quite large (439385 x 32)

```
             P12_neg    P29_neg    P14_neg     P3_neg   Gene    MAD
cg00008945 0.06834382 0.02129751 0.05877461 0.07455803    X1    n1
cg00011200 0.03415952 0.02044276 0.01593071 0.02513872    X1    n2
cg00018261 0.10386690 0.01565995 0.03092006 0.02627907    X2    n3
cg00026186 0.02339364 0.01111460 0.01287943 0.01242176    X2    n4
cg00026375 0.06322588 0.05420078 0.04394374 0.08865914    X3    n5
cg00043371 0.03288300 0.01759402 0.01939199 0.01499336    X3    n6
```

Edit.

I calculated the median absolute deviation, yes, using the function

```
 dataframe$MAD<-apply(dataframe,1,mads)
```

and found a solution to my problem.

To clarify what exactly I was referring to, if the MAD of row 2 was the highest of 
all rows corresponding to gene X1, and if the MAD of row 5 was the highest of all rows
associated with gene X3, and the MAD of row 4 was the highest of those associated with gene X2, I wanted to be able to pull out rows 2 (gene X1), 4 (gene X2) and 5 (gene X3)

The solution I alighted upon was to [1] order by decreasing order of MADS and [2] generate a vector of gene names and [3] use the match command

```
dataframe<-dataframe[rev(order(dataframe$MAD)),]
genes.vec<-as.character(dataframe$Gene[!duplicated(dataframe$Gene)])
dataframe2<-dataframe[match(genes.vec,dataframe$Gene),]
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried. E.g., I'm optimistic that you are able to calculate median absolute deviation for a given row.

Answer (score 0):

As Ronald stated in the comments you should tell us more specifically in which part you are struggling. Also, is good to provide a dummy example dataset and the expected results for that set. That way is possible to know better what is intended.

Is the selection criteria to maximize the SUM of deviation from the mean? If that's so, the next code does what you want. It is not optimized for speed, is intended to be easy to follow.

```
 sampleFrame=data.frame(P1=c(3,4,2,1,5,6),P2=c(2,4,6,10,2,7),
    Gene=c('X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X3'))

 dataCols = grep('^P',colnames(sampleFrame))
 namesCols = colnames(sampleFrame)[dataCols] 
 maximunsPerX = by(sampleFrame[,dataCols],sampleFrame[,'Gene'],function(x){   
   medians = apply(as.matrix(x),1,median)  
   names(medians) = NULL   
   mediansDesviation = abs(as.matrix(x) - medians)   
   sumOfMedianDesviation = colSums(mediansDesviation)    
   theMaximun = which.max(medians)   
   return(x[theMaximun,]) 
 })

 maxSample = do.call('rbind',maximunsPerX)
```